# Click every link on a web page with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs, phantomcss

I've been using [PhantomCSS](https://github.com/Huddle/PhantomCSS) to write visual regression tests with screenshots for a website. I want to simulate a click with [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org) on every `a` element on a page. I am able to retrieve every href and use `open` to visit each link, but I want to simulate a `click` event to have JavaScript interactions, etc. For some reason I haven't been able to find a way to do this.

I can get all the links on a page with:

```
  links = casper.evaluate(function(){
    var tags = __utils__.findAll('a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(tags, function(elem){
      return elem.href;
    });
  });
```

But [`casper.click()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#click) receives a selector as a parameter, and I have very generic links across this site. Seems like a pretty trivial task but for some reason I haven't found a way to do it.

Comment: You can also reduce your snippet to `casper.getElementsAttribute('a', 'href')` because `getElementsAttribute` is new in casper version 1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select a specific `a` element by the already collected `href`, but you should keep in mind how you want to structure your tests, because you need to begin with the web page for every link.

```
var url = "",   // some url
    links = []; // collected by your snippet
casper.eachThen(links, function(link){
    casper.thenOpen(url);
    casper.thenClick("a[href='"+link.data+"']"); // what you are looking for
    casper.then(function(){
        // your tests
    });
});
```

For this to work, I assume that the links are relatively unique: not all `href`s filled with `javascript:void(0)` or `#`. If this does not hold, you should clarify.

Comment: I think what I was needing the most was the correct XPath to click each link just having the href property. Thanks!